# If statement in for loop. How to break if 2/6 elements of array meet requirements

Tags: arrays, if-statement, for-loop, return, output

The int 'res' is an average of all 6 elements in the parts array. I have it working so that "Pass" will be displayed if:
1) The average (Res) is more than or equal to 60.
2) All elements of the array "parts" must be more than or equal to 55.
BUT
3) I need to also make "Pass" only print if 4 out of 6 elements in the array are smaller than 60 but a minimum of 55.

Any help with implimenting step three would be greatly appreciated! Thanks very much.

```
boolean output1 = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
 {
     if (parts[i] < 55 || res < 60)
        {
            output1 = false;
            break;
        }
 }
    if (output1)
    System.out.println("Pass");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to count the members that follow that condition.

```
boolean output1 = true;
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
 if(parts[i] < 55 || res < 60)
 {
  output1 = false;
  break;
 }
 if(parts[i] >= 55 && parts[i] < 60)
  ++counter;
}
if(output1 && counter >= 4)
 System.out.println("Pass");
```

You can also break the for loop if it is impossible to meet the condition (i.e. you are on third element and still you don't have any element that is greater than 54 and less than 60)

```
boolean output1 = true;
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
 if(parts[i] < 55 || res < 60)
 {
  output1 = false;
  break;
 }
 if(parts[i] >= 55 && parts[i] < 60)
  ++counter;
 if(i - counter > 2) //more than 2 did not match already
 {
  output1 = false;
  break;
 }
}
if(output1)
 System.out.println("Pass");
```